# Unity5 doesn't identify my player object

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am following the spaceship tutorial on Unity. In last minutes of this [video](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/projects/space-shooter/explosions), we are destroying the player ship as it contacts with asteroid. I do this by comparing the tags of which objects contacts with the asteroid. But it doesn't recognizes my tag. Here is my collision script on the asteroid object. My unity version is 5 but I think tutorials were taking with unity 4.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class DestroyByContact : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject explosion;
    public GameObject playerExplosion;

    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other) {
        if (other.tag == "Boundary") return;

        Instantiate(explosion, transform.position, transform.rotation);
        if (other.tag == "Player") {
            Debug.Log("We were here!"); // I can't see this in console.
            Instantiate(playerExplosion, other.transform.position, other.transform.rotation);
        }

        Destroy(other.gameObject);
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }

}
```

Comment: Could you show us your tag assignment? Or could you just print the tag you actually get?

Comment: @Bart I don't understand what you mean

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems okay to me and indeed, this tutorial was intended to be developed in Unity 4. I myself did it a year ago.

I think the problem could be in the Player tag or in the colliders. You are using trigger colliders in the asteroids, so check that the trigger checkbox is enabled in the collider attached to the asteroid. Also check that the script is enabled during runtime, it probably should be something like that.

You could check for the finished assets that every tutorial comes with, just to check that your asteroid has what it need to work properly.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: thanks for the tip, just trying to help here I dont understand why the downvote but thanks anyway

Comment: @WesFoster I respectfully disagree. I think this is a fine answer to the question.

Comment: @MaximillianLaumeister it could be seen either way I suppose. The answerer is providing tips as to what *could* potentially fix the proposed problem, however, the problem is still too unclear to be able to provide a concrete solution. This answer would have made a great comment to squeeze out additional information from the asker before providing a solution.